# Cannot import SpringApplicationContextLoader

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA and write Spring project.

I added dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and more related to Spring Boot.
I cannot import SpringApplicationContextLoader using:

import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader

But I see many projects on GitHub which use this class.

How can I check current package of this class?

Comment: why are you using <scope>test</scope>? you only use it in test phase?

Comment: I was thinking that is doesn't matter. I copied it from Maven Repository

Comment: I removed this line but it doesn't work still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following dependency to your pom:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

See:
https://1maven.com/idartifact/org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: How can I check which release has a specific class?

Answer (score 14):

According to javadoc of `SpringApplicatioNContextLoader` a.4.x it was deprecated in favor of `@SpringBootTest` or `SpringBootContextLoader` if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Solution provided by [Yoav Gur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5958449/yoav-gur) doesn't work for the latest spring-boot (1.5.2.RELEASE).

In my case I was looking for a solution to activate a spring profile for my cucumber tests. And I too found a lot of solutions which import this SpringApplicationContextLoader.class.
There is a class SpringBootContextLoader which might substitute for this, but I found another solution for my issues so didn't use it.

In case you're interested, you can find it here: 
[How to activate spring boot profile with cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203301/how-to-activate-spring-boot-profile-with-cucumber)

Comment: I have found [this](https://github.com/karlbennett/spring-boot-cucumber-example) example where `SpringApplicationContextLoader` is used. Version is `1.2.4`. In later version (`1.5.x` and above) of spring-boot this class does not exists. I have to find another solution.